# Средний рейтинг

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

В базе 4 и 5 среднее выводит 3.5 вместо 4.5

```
<?
$query="SELECT * FROM user_review WHERE id_user = '$id' AND rating > 0";
$run= mysqli_query($con,$query);

while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){

    $count=mysqli_num_rows($run);
    $rating += $row['rating'];
    var_dump($rating);
    $rating = $rating / $count;
}
    ?>
```

int(4) int(7)

Средний рейтинг 3.5

Answer (score 3):

просто для интереса - а почему среднее не вычислить уже в SQL запросе через `AVG`?

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_avg.asp

https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/4.5.php

А касательно вашего кода - смотрите какой треш происходит:

```
while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
    $rating += $row['rating'];
    $rating = $rating / $count;
}
```

т.е. для 4, 5 - происходит следующее

```
rating = 0 + 4 = 4
rating = 4 / 2 = 2

rating = 2 + 5 = 7
rating = 7 / 2 = 3.5
```

Зачем вы делите внутри цикла?!!!

Ваш код должен тогда быть таким:

```
$count=mysqli_num_rows($run);
$total = 0

while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){

    $total += $row['rating'];
}

$rating = $total / $count
```